# Map the index of nested array of numbers to the index of an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to map the array elements from foo3.flat() to the elements in foo2. An example would be if the 0th index in foo2 is 'address1' and the 0th index of foo3 is [1,2,3] all the individual numbers in [1,2,3] should be mapped to 'address1'. Currently, this is how obj is mapped.

**Value of obj**

```
{
  address1: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  address2: [ 4, 5 ],
  address3: [ 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  address4: [ 10 ]
}
```

**Code**

```
var foo1 = []

var foo2 = [
  'address1',
  'address2',
  'address3',
  'address4'
]

var foo3 = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5],
  [6,7,8,9],
  [10]
]

var foo4 = [
  [11,12,13],
  [14,15],
  [16,17,18,19],
  []
]


var foo5 = [
  [[111,111,111],[222,222,222],[333,333,333]],
  [[444,444,444],[555,555,555]],
  [[666,666,666],[777,777,777],[888,888,888],[999,999,999]],
  []
  
]

var obj = {}

foo2.forEach((key, i) => obj[key] = foo3[i])

foo3 = foo3.flat()
foo4 = foo4.flat()
foo5 = foo5.flat()


for(var i=0;i <foo3.length;i++) {
  
  foo1.push({
    key1:'',
    key2:foo3[i],
    key3:foo4[i],
    key4: foo5[i]
  })
}

console.log(foo1)
```

**Result**

```
[
  { key1: '', key2: 1, key3: 11, key4: [ 111, 111, 111 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 2, key3: 12, key4: [ 222, 222, 222 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 3, key3: 13, key4: [ 333, 333, 333 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 4, key3: 14, key4: [ 444, 444, 444 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 5, key3: 15, key4: [ 555, 555, 555 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 6, key3: 16, key4: [ 666, 666, 666 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 7, key3: 17, key4: [ 777, 777, 777 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 8, key3: 18, key4: [ 888, 888, 888 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 9, key3: 19, key4: [ 999, 999, 999 ] },
  { key1: '', key2: 10, key3: undefined, key4: undefined }
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
  { key1: 'address1', key2: 1, key3: 11, key4: [ 111, 111, 111 ] },
  { key1: 'address1', key2: 2, key3: 12, key4: [ 222, 222, 222 ] },
  { key1: 'address1', key2: 3, key3: 13, key4: [ 333, 333, 333 ] },
  { key1: 'address2', key2: 4, key3: 14, key4: [ 444, 444, 444 ] },
  { key1: 'address2', key2: 5, key3: 15, key4: [ 555, 555, 555 ] },
  { key1: 'address3', key2: 6, key3: 16, key4: [ 666, 666, 666 ] },
  { key1: 'address3', key2: 7, key3: 17, key4: [ 777, 777, 777 ] },
  { key1: 'address3', key2: 8, key3: 18, key4: [ 888, 888, 888 ] },
  { key1: 'address3', key2: 9, key3: 19, key4: [ 999, 999, 999 ] },
  { key1: 'address4', key2: 10, key3: undefined, key4: undefined }
]
```

```js
var foo1 = []

var foo2 = [
  'address1',
  'address2',
  'address3',
  'address4'
]

var foo3 = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9],
  [10]
]

var foo4 = [
  [11, 12, 13],
  [14, 15],
  [16, 17, 18, 19],
  []
]


var foo5 = [
  [
    [111, 111, 111],
    [222, 222, 222],
    [333, 333, 333]
  ],
  [
    [444, 444, 444],
    [555, 555, 555]
  ],
  [
    [666, 666, 666],
    [777, 777, 777],
    [888, 888, 888],
    [999, 999, 999]
  ],
  []

]

var obj = {}

foo2.forEach((key, i) => obj[key] = foo3[i])

foo3 = foo3.flat()
foo4 = foo4.flat()
foo5 = foo5.flat()


for (var i = 0; i < foo3.length; i++) {

  foo1.push({
    key1: '',
    key2: foo3[i],
    key3: foo4[i],
    key4: foo5[i]
  })
}

console.log(foo1)
```

Comment: `var length` is not being used.

Comment: @Taplar I just commented  it out it was leftover from a previous attempt

Comment: Also, you're always setting `key1` to an empty string in your loop.

Comment: @Taplar Yes just to have a placeholder, for now, I'm trying to set key1 to the matching 'address' from foo2

Comment: Added a runnable snippet of your code so we can see it in action.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you I'm currently trying to get the individual numbers to map back to the appropriate address where the empty strings are acting as placeholders

Answer (score 0):

here is a code that produces your expected result:

```js
var foo1 = [];

var foo2 = [
  'address1',
  'address2',
  'address3',
  'address4',
];

var foo3 = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9],
  [10],
];

var foo4 = [
  [11, 12, 13],
  [14, 15],
  [16, 17, 18, 19],
  [],
];


var foo5 = [
  [
    [111, 111, 111],
    [222, 222, 222],
    [333, 333, 333]
  ],
  [
    [444, 444, 444],
    [555, 555, 555]
  ],
  [
    [666, 666, 666],
    [777, 777, 777],
    [888, 888, 888],
    [999, 999, 999]
  ],
  [],
];

const map = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < foo2.length; i++) {
  const maxLength = Math.max(foo3[i].length, foo4[i].length, foo5[i].length);
  for (let j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
    map.set('key1', foo2[i]);
    map.set('key2', foo3[i][j]);
    map.set('key3', foo4[i][j]);
    map.set('key4', foo5[i][j]);
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(map);
    foo1.push(obj);
    map.clear();
  }
}

console.log(foo1);
```